# Two way binding between textbox from parent silverlight's page to another local silverlight user control's textbox

Tags: user-controls, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties

I have used DependencyProperty to pass value from textbox at silverlight page to external silverlight user control located in same page and that works fine.

But the problem is I could not bind the Textbox in page in reverse way. i.e. when i need to have changes in parent page when its usercontrol's textbox text is changed.

The XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextDataCollectionAccounts" Width="200" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBox>                    
<Local:CalControl   x:Name="RCal" DateRange="{Binding ElementName=TextDataCollectionAccounts, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

How to bind "TextDataCollectionAccounts"(in silverlight page) with Textbox of "Local:CalControl"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Basically never try to bind to the inner workings of a user control. Treat it like it was a third-party control and expose properties and events.*

- Expose the Text property of the TextBox as a *Text* dependency property on your usercontrol.
- Catch the change event of the TextBox and raise a property change event for the new *Text* dependency property.
- Then you can simply bind to your new *Text* property on your user control.

If you need a specific example, just ask, but it sounds like you are almost there and know your DPs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it would be nice to have a example. My idea is to get text of "Local:CalControl"(say textChildControl.text) in parent page TextDataCollectionAccounts.text. 

I tried the change text event handling of my user control's text property but I might did wrong somewhere its still don't work as i expected.

Comment: @webKite: This sort of stuff is easy to get wrong. Only takes 1 break in the chain. Can you provide source? It is then easy to give actual example. If it is confidential you can always contact me through my company website.

Comment: I have posted the code that i write for trying these things to work. Unfortunately its not working till now.

Comment: Finally, I figured out my mistakes and I solved them now. Thanks for you Help.